# opencv error: no GPU support

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I have install Cuda 6.5 and opencv 2.4.9 with visual studio 2010, when I run gpu, I get error

Opencv Error: No GPU support(the library is compiled without PGU support) in the row_nogpu, file C:/builds/2_4_Packslave-win32-vc10-shared/opencv/modules/gpu/src/precomp.hpp line 135

I get this error, is any one can help what do I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you have to actually build the libraries with CUDA support. I Imagine [This Guide](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/) will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused because of following.

1. **Use the flag `WITH_CUDA=ON` during `cmake`**
2. **You are trying to load the libraries which are compiled without GPU support, after you install opencv make sure you change the libraries path to that of GPU supported once.**